# Mule-How to convert payload into json

Tags: json, mule

I have this:

```
{a=1, b=2, c=3}, {a2=1, b2=2, c2=3}, {a3=1, b3=2, c3=3},
```

I need an output of json like this:

```
[{"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"}, {"a2":"1", "b2":"2", "c2":"3"}, {"a3":"1", "b3:2", "c3:3"}]
```

How to do so in Mule CE? Any Suggestions?

EDIT:

I have return data from magento `<magento:list-products/>`, and converted the payload like this:

```
    <json:object-to-json-transformer  doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
```

I had to do some filtering on that payload: used `<foreach/>` and for every product that fit the condition I saved in a variable like this:

```
 <set-variable variableName="productsInfoArr"
                value="#[flowVars.productsInfoArr.concat(flowVars.productInfo)+',']"/>
```

so the results are as above...

So basically the question is: how to create an array using json items?

Answer (score 1):

I take it you payload is a Java Collection of Maps. If so, simply use the:

```
<json:object-to-json-transformer />
```

Comment: when I do so I get this output: `"{a=1, b=2, c=3}, {a2=1, b2=2, c2=3}, {a3=1, b3=2, c3=3},"`...?

Comment: ok, your payload sounds like it is just a string. what Type is your payload?

Answer (score -1):

I usually use JSONArray to store the list of JSON object. In this case you might need to manipulate the input through Expression component:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression">
  <![CDATA[
    String input = payload.replaceAll("=", ":");
    input = input.replaceAll(",$", "");

    payload = new org.json.JSONArray("[" + input + "]");]]>
</expression-component>
```